# How to handle Firestone rules when creating a user with a specific ID scheme?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am creating a check in application where every user, that checks in, get's a specific uid from the follow scheme:

- A0001 - Z9999 (e.g. A1234, B0002, K5875)
  The letter and the number is ascending and will be generated with this function:

```js
  const generateUid = (fetched_id) => {
    let x = fetched_id.substr(0, 1);
    let y = fetched_id.substr(1, 4);
    if (y < 9999) {
      y++;
    } else {
      y = 1;
      x = String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
    }
    return `${x}${String(y).padStart(4, "0")}`;
  };
```

I am generating the user with the following logic:

- Log in anonymously
- Fetch the latest uid
- Generate a new uid with my custom function
- Add the user

```js
const generateUser = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInAnonymously()
      .then((loggedInUser) => {
        database
          .collection("users")
          .orderBy("uid", "desc")
          .limit(1)
          .get()
          .then((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((fetchedUser) => {
              const newUid = generateUid(fetchedUser.id);
              database
                .collection("users")
                .doc(newUid)
                .set({
                  name: user.name,
                  mail: user.mail,
                  tel: user.tel,
                  street: user.street,
                  zip: user.zip,
                  city: user.city,
                  date_checkin: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(
                    new Date()
                  ),
                  uid: newUid,
                  userId: loggedInUser.user.uid,
                })
                .then(() => {
                  setLoading(false);
                  history.push(`${folderPath}/checkedin/${newUid}-${uniqueId}`);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  console.log(error);
                  setLoading(false);
                });
            });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            setLoading(false);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

As I am fairly new to Firestone rules, I am wondering how I can handle read and write access.
The issues I see and where I am asking for a solution for are:

- I don't need an authentication generally, but I started to use it (`signInAnonymously()`) to only allow read and write when the user is logged in
- As I need the latest `uid` from `users` to generate a new one, I need read access, but this allows reading of every user what **absolutely needs to be not allowed**. *(It is necessary that the uid has this scheme and is ascending.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to store the last ID you generated as a single value in the database at a known path that all users can read and write, say a value `lastGeneratedID`.

You'll want to write security rules for this value to ensure the `lastGeneratedID` writes are always sequential and follow your naming scheme.

You'll want to use a transaction when clients are reading/writing the `lastGeneratedID` value, to ensure the clients automatically retry in case there are concurrent, conflicting updates.

Comment: and this happens everything within the rules code? Don't know that is that conflict and honestly your 2. and 3. doesn't help me a lot as I am very new to Firestore rules. Didn't ever use it on a production app. But your 1st Idea helps a lot

Comment: Unfortunately, it was not that helpful for me, as I don't get the point on the security rules where my question aimed at.

Comment: Good places to get started with that: https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+security+rules&oq=firestore+security+rules, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started, https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules

Comment: Thank you. After reading this articles I posted my question.

Comment: When I outsource the `lastGeneratedID` and everything is bullet-proof, I still have a `users` collection, where users (must) create there account and read there information, thus, they can read any information?!